# My screen turns grey when i put in my password

Tags: 22.04

I turned off my pc ti go to bed and then the next morning when I went to turn it back on the screen turned grey after i typed in my password. I have tried reloading it a couple times but it stayed the same. I am using Ubuntu 22.04.3.
I have had this kind of problem before but it was after the loading screen that it turned blachk and had a terminal thing at the top left corner.

Comment: Did you try a hard shutdown, and reboot? Hold power button down 5 seconds.